# How to save multiple values into a list when reading from a csv file?

Tags: python, list, csv

I have been able to read in my list of data from my csv file and when I print it on its own it outputs it on its own line as a list:

```
['51-4678119', 'Issie', 'Scholard', '11 Texas Court', 'Columbia', 'Missouri', '65218', '3', '134386.51', '34', '91.06']
['68-9609244', 'Jed', 'Netti', '85 Coolidge Terrace', 'San Antonio', 'Texas', '78255', '2', '159648.55', '47', '45.7']
['47-2771794', 'Galvan', 'Solesbury', '3 Drewry Junction', 'Springfield', 'Illinois', '62794', '2', '91934.89', '39', '47.92']
['11-0469486', 'Reynard', 'Lorenzin', '3233 Spaight Point', 'Houston', 'Texas', '77030', '1', '87578.56', '27', '86.84']
```

I want to be able to put all the contents of the out put into its own list.
here is my code so far:

```
import csv
empList = []
with open ('employees.csv') as employees:
    reader = csv.reader(employees)
    header = next(reader)
    if header != None:
        for row in reader:
            print(row)
```

Comment: Would you want `empList.append(row)`?

Answer (score 1):

The `.append()` method will add a new item to the end of a list. If you replace your print(row) with `empList.append(row)`, and then `print(empList)`, you will get a single list that contains a bunch of lists within it.

```
import csv
empList = []
with open (r'desktop\employees.csv') as employees:
    reader = csv.reader(employees)
    header = next(reader)
    if header != None:
        for row in reader:
            empList.append(row)
            
print(empList)
```

For returns the following:
 `[['68-9609244', ' Jed', ' Netti', ' 85 Coolidge Terrace', ' San Antonio', ' Texas', ' 78255', ' 2', ' 159648.55', ' 47', ' 45.7'], ['47-2771794', ' Galvan', ' Solesbury', ' 3 Drewry Junction', ' Springfield', ' Illinois', ' 62794', ' 2', ' 91934.89', ' 39', ' 47.92'], ['11-0469486', ' Reynard', ' Lorenzin', ' 3233 Spaight Point', ' Houston', ' Texas', ' 77030', ' 1', ' 87578.56', ' 27', ' 86.84']]`